# jQuery clone( true ) not working with dynamic elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone

Take the following example:

```
$.fn.foo = function() {

    var $input = $('<input type="text"/>');
    var $button_one = $('<button>One</button>');
    var $button_two = $('<button>Two</button>');

    $button_one.click(function(){
        $input.val('hey');
    });

    $button_two.click(function(){
        $input.replaceWith( $input.val('').clone( true ) );
    });

    this.append( $input, $button_one, $button_two );


};
```

Check the demo: http://jsbin.com/ezexah/1/edit

Now click "one" and you should see "hey" in the input. Next click "two" and then click "one" again and it doesn't work. Even using the `true` option in `clone` to copy all events it still does not work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not update `$input`. It is still referring to the element you just removed, meaning `$input.val('hey');` will update the value of the DOM element that is now detached from the DOM tree.
`.clone` or `.replaceWith` do not automatically update existing references:

```
var $clone = $input.val('').clone( true )
$input.replaceWith($clone);
$input = $clone;
```

This has nothing to do with the `true` option btw, because you did not bind any event handlers to `$input`.

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/ezexah/7/edit)

Comment: You're right, actually I just found this myself after asking the question. I ended up with this one liner `$input.replaceWith( $input  = $input.clone( true ) )`. Will accept in 5 min.